# Laravel eloquent with() returns null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8

```
namespace App;

use App\Model\Service\Area;
use App\Model\Bid\Service;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Bid extends Model
{
    protected $table = "bid";

    protected $primaryKey = 'bid_id';

    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $with = ['services'];

    public function services() {
        return $this->hasMany(Service::class, 'bid_id');
    }

    public function area() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Area::class, 'area_id', 'area_id');
    }
}
```

```
namespace App\Model\Service;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Area extends Model
{
    protected $table = "location_area";

    protected $primaryKey = 'area_id';

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function city()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(City::class, 'city_id');
    }
}
```

> [Area table Migration and data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TIEE.png)
>
> [Bid table Migration and data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2VH6.png)

**When I am trying to access**

```
Bid::with('area')->find(BID_ID);
```

**It is returning Null**
Query is firing wrong:

```
"select * from `location_area` where `location_area`.`area_id` in (0)"
```

But if I am doing like:

```
$bid = Bid::find(BID_ID);
dd($bid->area);
```

> It returns Area table values. What is going wrong? Please Help me.  I
> am having this problem for a long time. Thank You in advance :)

Comment: Hi, and how looks your controller? What do you return?

Comment: Do you have a `area_id` column on both your Area table and Bid table? Is there a row on the Area table that has that specific `area_id`?

Comment: Try to change in `Bid.php` `public function area() {
        return $this->hasOne(Area::class, 'area_id', 'area_id');
    }`

Comment: Do you have related data in `location_area` table?

Comment: @LinusJuhlin   Yes, I have verified that.

Comment: Hi. It will be helpful if  you explore statements around the code `Bid::with('area')->find(BID_ID);` for example, how you are getting value in `BID_ID`. Also some code from your migration or table structure - especially table 'Bid'.

Comment: @balkal I am passing the request from my Vue component using Axios to controller to fetch data about a particular bid.

Router:
`Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/fetch/bid/{id}', 'UserController@bid')->where('id', '[0-9]{15}+');
});
`
Controller:
`class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function bid($bid_id) {
        return Bid::with('area')->findOrFail($bid_id);
    }
}
`

Comment: @kritesh Dusane Looking at your table location_area, I think the accepted answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510599/cant-retrieve-column-value-from-laravels-eloquent-when-primary-key-is-varchar may solve your query.

Comment: @balkal Hey man, Thank you so much. This solved my issue.

Comment: Welcome boss :)

Answer (score 1):

you must be declared a method in your **MID model**

```
    public function area()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Area::class, 'bid');
        }
```

something like this
after this, you access area in `with()`

```
Bid::with('area')->find(BID_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this function in your Bid model :

```
 public function area() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Area::class, 'area_id');
    }
```